# How to Group by two colunms?

Tags: sql

**Table:**

[image]

**query:**

```
SELECT cintitule , cperiode , SUM(nmontant) FROM tsal_mois 
WHERE cperiode between "201901" AND "201912" 
GROUP BY cperiode, cintitule
```

**result:**

[image]

**Problem:**

I want to group by 'cperiode' column.

eg.: the result I want

```
                                 "date"
ccodrub    cintitule            all-cperiode           sum_nmontant
 001       Salaire de Base          2019               (I want all 
 001       Salaire de Base          2018               sum of all in 2019)    
                                    (I want all
                                    the years
                                      grouped by)
                        " the dates are by months
                          I want it by year"
```

**edit**
this query is what I need :

```
SELECT ccodrub, cintitule  , SUM(nmontant) FROM tsal_mois WHERE cperiode between "201901" AND "201912" GROUP BY  cintitule , ccodrub
```

**thank you**

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  It is also not clear where `ccodrub` comes from; it is in the results, but not in the query.

Comment: thank you for replying, the ccodrub is in both the talbe and the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for, this query solve my problem, thank you all

```
SELECT ccodrub, cintitule  , SUM(nmontant) FROM tsal_mois WHERE cperiode between "201901" AND "201912" GROUP BY  cintitule , ccodrub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string (or mathematical) functions to extract the year.  Assuming that `cperiode` is a string:

```
SELECT cintitule , LEFT(cperiode, 4) as year, SUM(nmontant)
FROM tsal_mois 
WHERE cperiode between '201901"'AND '201912'
GROUP BY cintitule, LEFT(cperiode, 4);
```

Most databases support `LEFT()`, for those that don't use the appropriate function.

If `cperiod` is actually a number, then use `FLOOR(cperiod/100)` instead.